# -k and -l options in rysnc

Tags: rsync

When read the manual of `rsync`, I found that

```
    -l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
    -L, --copy-links            transform symlink into referent file/dir
        --copy-unsafe-links     only "unsafe" symlinks are transformed
        --safe-links            ignore symlinks that point outside the tree
        --munge-links           munge symlinks to make them safer
    -k, --copy-dirlinks         transform symlink to dir into referent dir
    -K, --keep-dirlinks         treat symlinked dir on receiver as dir
```

`-l` match to `-K` and `-L` to '-k`

The -k and -K is but a redundancy of  -l and -L ,

Does they just compatible backwards or have any distinctions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the excerpt below

> -l, --links
>   When symlinks are encountered, recreate the symlink on the destination.
>
> -k, --copy-dirlinks
>       This option causes the sending side to treat a symlink to a directory as though it were a real directory.
>       This is useful if you don't want symlinks to non-directories to be affected, as they would be using --copy-links.
>
> Without this option, if the sending side has replaced a directory with a symlink to a directory, the
>       receiving side will delete anything that is in the way of the new symlink, including a directory hierarchy
>       (as long as --force or --delete is in effect).
>
> See also --keep-dirlinks for an analogous option for the receiving side.
>
> --copy-dirlinks applies to all symlinks to directories in the source. If you want to follow only a
>       few specified symlinks, a trick you can use is to pass them as additional source args with a trailing slash,
>       using --relative to make the paths match up right. For example:
>
> ```
>   rsync -r --relative src/./ src/./follow-me/ dest/
> ```
>
> This works because rsync calls lstat(2) on the source arg as given, and the trailing slash makes lstat(2)
>       follow the symlink, giving rise to a directory in the file-list which overrides the symlink found
>       during the scan of "src/./".
>
> -L, --copy-links
>       When symlinks are encountered, the item that they point to (the referent) is copied, rather than the symlink.
>       In older versions of rsync, this option also had the side-effect of telling the receiving side to
>       follow symlinks, such as symlinks to directories. In a modern rsync such as this one, you'll need to
>       specify --keep-dirlinks (-K) to get this extra behavior.
>       The only exception is when sending files to an rsync that is too old to understand -K -- in that case,
>       the -L option will still have the side-effect of -K on that older receiving rsync.
>
> -K, --keep-dirlinks
>       This option causes the receiving side to treat a symlink to a directory as though it were a real directory,
>       but only if it matches a real directory from the sender. Without this option, the receiver's symlink would
>       be deleted and replaced with a real directory.
>
> For example, suppose you transfer a directory "foo" that contains a file "file", but "foo" is a symlink
>       to directory "bar" on the receiver. Without --keep-dirlinks, the receiver deletes symlink "foo", recreates
>       it as a directory, and receives the file into the new directory. With --keep-dirlinks, the receiver keeps
>       the symlink and "file" ends up in "bar".
>
> One note of caution: if you use --keep-dirlinks, you must trust all the symlinks in the copy! If it is
>       possible for an untrusted user to create their own symlink to any directory, the user could then
>       (on a subsequent copy) replace the symlink with a real directory and affect the content of whatever
>       directory the symlink references. For backup copies, you are better off using something like a bind
>       mount instead of a symlink to modify your receiving hierarchy.
>
> See also --copy-dirlinks for an analogous option for the sending side.

For case of `-L` and `-K`:

- `-L`: When symlinks are encountered, the item that they point to (the referent) is copied, rather than the symlink.
- `-K`: This option causes the receiving side to treat a symlink to a directory as though it were a real directory,
  but only if it matches a real directory from the sender. Without this option, the receiver's symlink would
  be deleted and replaced with a real directory.

For case of `-l` and `-k`:

- `-l`: When symlinks are encountered, recreate the symlink on the destination.
- `-k`: This option causes the sending side to treat a symlink to a directory as though it were a real directory.
  This is useful if you don't want symlinks to non-directories to be affected, as they would be using --copy-links.

See: https://ss64.com/bash/rsync_options.html